# Moving emails to pinned, not mapped, folder on Hard Drive

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive emails on a regular basis from a customer. I need to save these emails into a folder on my local Hard Drive in a folder with the current date.

I found code that helps and allows me to select or create folders. The pinned folders which is where I want to save the files to is not an option.  When I browse the folders that has the emails I want to save. It prompts to save into another folder, with an option to create it.

It also bombs out with

> Run-time error code '76': Path not found

after creating a folder.

The folder is visible in file explorer, but when checking for the path, it is not going to the newly created path.

We use pinned network drives because we cannot access mapped drives when working remotely.

My goal is to create a folder on the HD and move selected emails. I could specify the sender if it would be easier.

Code I found on another site.

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Sub SaveAllEmails_ProcessAllSubFolders()
    
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim n               As Long
    Dim StrSubject      As String
    Dim StrName         As String
    Dim StrFile         As String
    Dim StrReceived     As String
    Dim StrSavePath     As String
    Dim StrFolder       As String
    Dim StrFolderPath   As String
    Dim StrSaveFolder   As String
    Dim Prompt          As String
    Dim Title           As String
    Dim iNameSpace      As NameSpace
    Dim myOlApp         As Outlook.Application
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    Dim mItem           As MailItem
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ChosenFolder    As Object
    Dim Folders         As New Collection
    Dim EntryID         As New Collection
    Dim StoreID         As New Collection
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ChosenFolder = iNameSpace.PickFolder
    If ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If
    
    Prompt = "Please enter the path to save all the emails to."
    Title = "Folder Specification"
    StrSavePath = BrowseForFolder
    If StrSavePath = "" Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If
    If Not Right(StrSavePath, 1) = "\" Then
        StrSavePath = StrSavePath & "\"
    End If
    
    Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)
    
    For i = 1 To Folders.Count
        StrFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
        n = InStr(3, StrFolder, "\") + 1
        StrFolder = Mid(StrFolder, n, 256)
        StrFolderPath = StrSavePath & StrFolder & "\"
        StrSaveFolder = Left(StrFolderPath, Len(StrFolderPath) - 1) & "\"
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(StrFolderPath) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (StrFolderPath)
        End If
        
        Set SubFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
        On Error Resume Next
        For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
            Set mItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
            StrReceived = ArrangedDate(mItem.ReceivedTime)
            StrSubject = mItem.Subject
            StrName = StripIllegalChar(StrSubject)
            StrFile = StrSaveFolder & StrReceived & "_" & StrName & ".msg"
            StrFile = Left(StrFile, 256)
            mItem.SaveAs StrFile, 3
        Next j
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    
ExitSub:
    
End Sub
 
Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    
    Dim RegX            As Object
    
    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True
    
    StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")
    
ExitFunction:
    
    Set RegX = Nothing
    
End Function
 
 
Function ArrangedDate(StrDateInput)
    
    Dim StrFullDate     As String
    Dim StrFullTime     As String
    Dim StrAMPM         As String
    Dim StrTime         As String
    Dim StrYear         As String
    Dim StrMonthDay     As String
    Dim StrMonth        As String
    Dim StrDay          As String
    Dim StrDate         As String
    Dim StrDateTime     As String
    Dim RegX            As Object
    
    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
    If Not Left(StrDateInput, 2) = "10" And _
    Not Left(StrDateInput, 2) = "11" And _
    Not Left(StrDateInput, 2) = "12" Then
        StrDateInput = "0" & StrDateInput
    End If
    
    StrFullDate = Left(StrDateInput, 10)
    
    If Right(StrFullDate, 1) = " " Then
        StrFullDate = Left(StrDateInput, 9)
    End If
    
    StrFullTime = Replace(StrDateInput, StrFullDate & " ", "")
    
    If Len(StrFullTime) = 10 Then
        StrFullTime = "0" & StrFullTime
    End If
    
    StrAMPM = Right(StrFullTime, 2)
    StrTime = StrAMPM & "-" & Left(StrFullTime, 8)
    StrYear = Right(StrFullDate, 4)
    StrMonthDay = Replace(StrFullDate, "/" & StrYear, "")
    StrMonth = Left(StrMonthDay, 2)
    StrDay = Right(StrMonthDay, Len(StrMonthDay) - 3)
    If Len(StrDay) = 1 Then
        StrDay = "0" & StrDay
    End If
    StrDate = StrYear & "-" & StrMonth & "-" & StrDay
    StrDateTime = StrDate & "_" & StrTime
    RegX.Pattern = "[\:\/\ ]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True
    
    ArrangedDate = RegX.Replace(StrDateTime, "-")
    
ExitFunction:
    
    Set RegX = Nothing
    
End Function
 
Sub GetFolder(Folders As Collection, EntryID As Collection, StoreID As Collection, Fld As MAPIFolder)
    
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    
    Folders.Add Fld.FolderPath
    EntryID.Add Fld.EntryID
    StoreID.Add Fld.StoreID
    For Each SubFolder In Fld.Folders
        GetFolder Folders, EntryID, StoreID, SubFolder
    Next SubFolder
    
ExitSub:
    
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    
End Sub
 
 
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
    
    Dim ShellApp As Object
    
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then
            BrowseForFolder = ""
        End If
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            BrowseForFolder = ""
        End If
    Case Else
        BrowseForFolder = ""
    End Select
    
ExitFunction:
    
    Set ShellApp = Nothing
    
End Function
```

I posted this on another site, but haven't received any response.